# Find $dy/dx$ at $x = 2$, if $y= u ^ 3$ , and $u= x^2-1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Need help setting this thing up don't really get how to get the derivative is it $0$? If you just plug everything in since there will be no variable.

Comment: **Hint:** $y = (x^2-1)^3$, find the derivative $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, evaluate at $x = 2$.

Comment: Also, you don't plug in $x=2$ first. First, you calculate the derivative. And then plug in $x$.

Comment: Ahh so basically you do the chain rule and then plug it in? That's what I was confused with I thought you just plug everything in including the x in the equation and then try differentiate it. In that case 108?

Comment: Correct ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it I was confused whether you plug everything in at first which I was stuck at you have to find derivative first, then plug the x and get your answer
Y= 6*2(2^2-1)^2= 108

Thanks for the help

Comment: By the way, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial. and may be you will  be interested inreading [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

$dy/dx=dy/du×du/dx$

$dy/dx=3 u^2×2 x=3 (x^2-1)^2×2 x=6 x(x^2-1)^2$

$Then  x=2$

$dy/dx_(x=2)=108$

Comment: To make your answer look nicer, format fractions by doing \frac{numerator}{denominator} instead of numerator/denominator. I don't have editing priveleges so it's easier if you change it yourself.